# VB6 3-dimensional array. How to add values by searching so that the values are grouped?

Tags: arrays, 3d, vb6

I have this data inside a file and I'm trying to read it line by line. The 1st column is the user #, the 2nd is the date, the 3rd is the the time. The rest are ignored.

```
    1   2016-11-09 08:03:51 1   0   1   0
    2   2016-11-09 08:03:51 1   0   1   0
    1   2016-11-09 11:22:00 1   1   1   0
    2   2016-11-09 11:22:00 1   1   1   0
    1   2016-11-09 13:29:06 1   1   1   0
    2   2016-11-09 13:33:08 1   0   1   0
    1   2016-11-09 05:17:49 1   0   1   0
    2   2016-11-09 05:17:49 1   0   1   0
    1   2016-11-10 08:03:51 1   0   1   0
    2   2016-11-10 08:03:51 1   0   1   0
    1   2016-11-10 11:22:00 1   1   1   0
    2   2016-11-10 11:22:00 1   1   1   0
    1   2016-11-10 13:29:06 1   1   1   0
    2   2016-11-10 13:33:08 1   0   1   0
    1   2016-11-10 05:17:49 1   0   1   0
    2   2016-11-10 05:17:49 1   0   1   0
```

I already have a function that reads the entire file line by line, split each line and store each column in a string array.

```
Dim strEmpFileName  As String
Dim strBackSlash  As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr As Integer

Dim strLine    As String
Dim strSplit1()    As String
Dim strSplit2()    As String
Dim attRecord(0 To 99, 0 To 30, 0 To 3) As String

strBackSlash = IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) = "\", "", "\")
strEmpFileName = App.Path & strBackSlash & "1_attlog.dat"
intEmpFileNbr = FreeFile

Open strEmpFileName For Input As #intEmpFileNbr

Do Until EOF(intEmpFileNbr)
    Input #intEmpFileNbr, strLine
    strSplit1() = Split(strLine, vbTab)
    strSplit2() = Split(strSplit1(1)) '<-- separate date and time (space delimited)
    Print strSplit1(0); Tab(5); strSplit2(0); Tab(18); strSplit2(1)
    'Shows: 1    2016-11-09    08:03:51
Loop
Close #intEmpFileNbr
```

Now my problem is, I wanted to save the values in a 3 dimensional array which should look like the one below. VB6 is the limit, so I cannot use another language for this.

```
3 dimensional array: (user# upto 99, days of the month (31), 4 timestamp per day)

1 -> 2016-11-01 -> {08:03:51, 11:22:00, 13:29:06, 05:17:49}
     2016-11-02 -> {07:55:25, 11:30:07, 13:45:11, 05:05:12}
       upto
     2016-11-30 -> {08:15:23, 11:25:45, 13:23:02, 05:00:57}

2 -> 2016-11-01 -> {08:03:51, 11:22:00, 13:29:06, 05:17:49}
     2016-11-02 -> {07:55:25, 11:30:07, 13:45:11, 05:05:12}
       upto
     2016-11-30 -> {08:15:23, 11:25:45, 13:23:02, 05:00:57}
```

I think this would require searching the whole array to know if the date for that user is already existing then add the additional timestamp for that date.

The goal is to be able to calculate the number of days and number of hours per day per user.

Comment: If user id is a fixed number like 0 to 99 and days of the month is a fixed number 0 to 30 (I assume you ignore the month, so Nov 15th is the same as Dec 15th), then you don't need to loop through the whole array. You can assume that customer #20, on Nov 15th 2016 is YourArray(20,15, X). This way you only need to loop through the time elements X to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can either:

a. Sort the lines first. This will automatically group them. Then loop over the results and count.

b. Recursively. Change the array data structure into a tree. Each user will have a node, it's children will be the days, and it's children will be the hours.

A generic recursive solution for populating such a data structure is to use the Dictonary object (you will need to include the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference):

```
Private Sub AddItem(ByRef oDict As Dictionary, ParamArray vItems() As Variant)
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim oThisDict As Dictionary
    Dim oNewDict As Dictionary

    Set oThisDict = oDict
    For Each vItem In vItems
        If oThisDict.Exists(vItem) Then
            Set oThisDict = oThisDict(CStr(vItem))
        Else
            Set oNewDict = New Dictionary
            oThisDict.Add CStr(vItem), oNewDict
            Set oThisDict = oNewDict
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As a sidenote this sub converts the incoming values to strings.

You can populate this structure something like this:

```
Dim oDict As New Dictionary

AddItem oDict, strSplit1(0), strSplit2(0), strSplit2(1)
```

You do the AddItem call for each line of the file.

At the end you can simply use for example:

```
debug.print oDict.Item("1").Count
```

to get a count of the number of dates for user 1. If you don't know the users then you can loop through the oDict.Keys collection:

```
Dim vUser As Variant

For Each vUser In oDict.Keys
    Debug.Print vUser
Next
```

Hopefully, that's enough for you to work out the rest. Note that Dictionary objects work with Variant types, that's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: I actually tried what you suggested. And although it works, I still got  stuck on other problems arising along the way. So I ended up using PHP, and has been done perfectly. But I'm still gonna accept your answer. Thanks.